# Mapping Json with nested array using ObjectMapper Swift 3

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift3

Here is my returning JSON :

```
[ {
    "question": {
        "ID": 110,
        "SurveyID": 12,
        "Question": "...",
        "QuestionType": "CTS",
        "QuestionOrder": 1,
        "Status": "1",
        "QuestionSubType": null,
        "QuestionIndex": null
    },
    "options": [{
            "ID": 311,
            "SurveyID": 12,
            "QuestionID": 110,
            "OptionText": "...",
            "IsOther": null,
            "Status": "1",
            "ImageUrl": null,
            "BranchId": null,
            "NextQuestionID": null
        },
        {
            "ID": 312,
            "SurveyID": 12,
            "QuestionID": 110,
            "OptionText": "...",
            "IsOther": null,
            "Status": "1",
            "ImageUrl": null,
            "BranchId": null,
            "NextQuestionID": null
        },
        {
            "ID": 313,
            "SurveyID": 12,
            "QuestionID": 110,
            "OptionText": "...",
            "IsOther": null,
            "Status": "1",
            "ImageUrl": null,
            "BranchId": null,
            "NextQuestionID": null
        },
        {
            "ID": 314,
            "SurveyID": 12,
            "QuestionID": 110,
            "OptionText": "...",
            "IsOther": null,
            "Status": "1",
            "ImageUrl": null,
            "BranchId": null,
            "NextQuestionID": null
        }
    ],
}, {
    "question": {
        "ID": 117,
        "SurveyID": 12,
        "Question": " ...",
        "QuestionType": "CTS",
        "QuestionOrder": 2,
        "Status": "1",
        "QuestionSubType": null,
        "QuestionIndex": null
    },
    "options": [{
            "ID": 315,
            "SurveyID": 12,
            "QuestionID": 117,
            "OptionText": "...",
            "IsOther": null,
            "Status": "1",
            "ImageUrl": null,
            "BranchId": null,
            "NextQuestionID": null
        },
        {
            "ID": 316,
            "SurveyID": 12,
            "QuestionID": 117,
            "OptionText": "...",
            "IsOther": null,
            "Status": "1",
            "ImageUrl": null,
            "BranchId": null,
            "NextQuestionID": null
        },
        {
            "ID": 317,
            "SurveyID": 12,
            "QuestionID": 117,
            "OptionText": "...",
            "IsOther": null,
            "Status": "1",
            "ImageUrl": null,
            "BranchId": null,
            "NextQuestionID": null
        }
    ],
},
....
} ]
```

Here is my models :

```
class Question : Mappable{

    var ID : Int?
    var SurveyID : Int?
    var Question : String?
    var QuestionType : String?
    var QuestionOrder : Int?
    var options : [Option]?

    required init?(map : Map){}

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        options <- map["options"]
        ID <- map["ID"]
        SurveyID <- map["SurveyID"]
        Question <- map["Question"]
        QuestionType <- map["QuestionType"]
        QuestionOrder <- map["QuestionOrder"]
    }    
}

class Option : Mappable{

    var QuestionID : Int?
    var OptionText : String?
    var ImageUrl : String?
    var NextQuestionID : Int?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        QuestionID <- map["QuestionID"]
        OptionText <- map["QuestionText"]
        ImageUrl <- map["ImageUrl"]
        NextQuestionID <- map["NextQuestionID"]
    }
}
```

How I could do it so far :

```
var questions = [Question]()
    Alamofire.request(retrieveQuestionsURL(1, branchId: 1, surveyId: 12) , method: .get , headers : headers).responseJSON{
                response in
                switch response.result{
                case .success (let data):
                    self.questions = Mapper<Question>().mapArray(JSONArray: (data as? [[String: Any]])!)!
                case .failure (let err):
                    print(err)
                }
                self.removeAllOverlays()
                let json = Mapper().toJSONArray(self.questions)
                print("questions" , json)
            }
```

Output :

```
[
    [
        "options": ["QuestionID": 110, "OptionText": "..."],
        ["QuestionID": 110, "OptionText": "..."],
        ["QuestionID": 110, "OptionText": "..."],
        ["QuestionID": 110, "OptionText": "..."]
    ]
], [
    "options": [
        [
            "QuestionID": 117, "OptionText": "..."
        ],
        ["QuestionID": 117, "OptionText": "..."],
        ["QuestionID": 117, "OptionText": "..."]
    ]
],
......
]
```

It mapped just nested array , where is SurveyID,Question etc.  How can i accomplish this correctly formatted? I searched web nested array mapping but I couldn't find any useful information. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your implementation of Map, Mapper and Mappable?

Comment: What do you mean , I just posted whole mappable classes? What do you need specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is : I didn't analyze returning JSON very well. SurveyID , Question etc. is an element of "question" object. So I edited my mappable classes like below :

```
    ID <- map["question.ID"]
    SurveyID <- map["question.SurveyID"]
    Question <- map["question.Question"]
    QuestionType <- map["question.QuestionType"]
    QuestionOrder <- map["question.QuestionOrder"]
```

This works in my case. I hope this solution will help somebody. Happy coding